# Libreoffice considering ordinary text as headings

Tags: styles, libreoffice-writer, table-of-contents

I am preparing my thesis with several headings and subheadings. In fact I started writing the report first and later went on to add pages in the beginning to insert title page, certificate, abstract, acknowledgements and table of contents and so on. In the title page I have defined a set of custom fonts for the name of report and other details. I have set the custom fonts this way:

1. Name: Doc_title; Next Style: Default; Linked with: Default; Outline level: Body Text; Numbering style: None
2. Name: Tit_cont1; Next style: Tit_cont1; Linked with: Default; Outline level: Body Text; Numbering style: None

Rest of the contents in these first set of pages use `text body` style.

Now my problem is when I generate the table of contents, all the contents of previous pages i.e, title page, certificate etc. appear in table of contents. I could of course delete them but I want to set this problem right. So I am asking here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved the problem with these steps: I selected the text and in the context menu instead of selecting `Edit Paragraph Style` I selected `Paragraph`. To my surprise though I had selected `Outline Level` as `Body Text` in `Outline and numbering` of `Edit Paragraph style`, it was still `Level 1` in `Paragraph`'s `Outline Level`. Once I changed it to `Body Text` everything went fine.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly define my own styles and for the table of contents (TOC) use only them. When inserting the TOC, you can check which styles should be used to build it. I usually uncheck the normal ones and check *Other style*s - after clicking on "..." you can assign the custom styles to every TOC level.

Answer (score -1):

I also found selecting the paragraphs and Format -> Clear Direct Formatting also resolves the issue. Beats having to do them one by one.